# Pandas find minimum of date (NOT DATETIME) column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a pandas dataframe `df` where a column `Datetime` is a datetime object. If I do:

```
df['Datetime'].min()
```

pandas returns the correct answer - the earliest date available. But if I want to work with date objects instead of datetimes, and create subsequently a `Date` that is a datetime.date object as in:

```
df['Date'] = df['Datetime'].dt.date
df['Date'].min()
```

I get back

```
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'datetime.date'
```

Is that a pandas bug? How can I workaround it? I am using python 3.6, pandas 0.20.3

Comment: What is reason for working with `date`s? Then lost all vectorized `.dt` operation. I suggest use `df['Datetime'].dt.floor('d')` and working with `datetime`s if possible.

Comment: Thanks @jezrael I was using pandas 0.20.3. Your solution works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In pandas `0.23.0` your code working nice if no `NaT` values:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2017-04-03 14:10:01', periods=10, freq='15H')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Datetime': rng, 'a': range(10)})  

df['Date'] = df['Datetime'].dt.date
print (df['Date'].min())

2017-04-03
```

```
rng = pd.date_range('2017-04-03 14:10:01', periods=10, freq='15H')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Datetime': rng, 'a': range(10)})  
df.loc[len(df), 'Date'] = np.nan
df['Date'] = df['Datetime'].dt.date

print (df)
              Datetime    a        Date
0  2017-04-03 14:10:01  0.0  2017-04-03
1  2017-04-04 05:10:01  1.0  2017-04-04
2  2017-04-04 20:10:01  2.0  2017-04-04
3  2017-04-05 11:10:01  3.0  2017-04-05
4  2017-04-06 02:10:01  4.0  2017-04-06
5  2017-04-06 17:10:01  5.0  2017-04-06
6  2017-04-07 08:10:01  6.0  2017-04-07
7  2017-04-07 23:10:01  7.0  2017-04-07
8  2017-04-08 14:10:01  8.0  2017-04-08
9  2017-04-09 05:10:01  9.0  2017-04-09
10                 NaT  NaN         NaT

print (df['Date'].min())
```

> TypeError: unorderable types: datetime.date() <= float()

---

Solutions working nice with `NaT`s:

```
#alternative
print (min(df['Date'].tolist()))
#print (min(df['Date'].values))

2017-04-03
```

---

Another solution:

Use [`floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) by `day`s for return `datetime`s instead `date`s:

```
df['Date'] = df['Datetime'].dt.floor('d')
```

**Sample**:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2017-04-03 14:10:01', periods=10, freq='15H')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Datetime': rng, 'a': range(10)})  

df['Date'] = df['Datetime'].dt.floor('d')
print (df)
             Datetime  a       Date
0 2017-04-03 14:10:01  0 2017-04-03
1 2017-04-04 05:10:01  1 2017-04-04
2 2017-04-04 20:10:01  2 2017-04-04
3 2017-04-05 11:10:01  3 2017-04-05
4 2017-04-06 02:10:01  4 2017-04-06
5 2017-04-06 17:10:01  5 2017-04-06
6 2017-04-07 08:10:01  6 2017-04-07
7 2017-04-07 23:10:01  7 2017-04-07
8 2017-04-08 14:10:01  8 2017-04-08
9 2017-04-09 05:10:01  9 2017-04-09

print (df['Datetime'].min())
2017-04-03 14:10:01

print (df['Datetime'].min().date())
2017-04-03
```